# Ubuntu: забыл запустить screen на долгий процесс

Tags: linux, redirect, консоль, gnu-screen

Привет.

Запустил сборку пакета и забыл, что это не моя рабочая машина, а другая, где screen не запускается автоматом и сборка будет длиться несколько часов, а не несколько минут, как когда полная сборка уже была произведена когда-то. Стал думать, что делать. ^Z приостановит процесс, но он все еще привязан к терминалу. Нагуглить способ, которым можно переподключить терминал или перенаправить вывод в файл я не нашел. Нашел, что при помощи disown я могу отсоединить терминал, но как бы его подключить с screen или перенаправить в файл? Как я понимаю, вопрос для самых гуру линукса. Пожалуйста, не пишите глупых комментариев, не относящихся к теме вопроса. Спасибо.

Comment: http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html